# Add some extra text(html+content) before start view. (Within the div from the view)

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to put some extra hard coded HTML into a view before the sum of the view starts.

[www.peace-in-the-city.be](http://www.peace-in-the-city.be)

On the homepage you see a section 'visitors'... it shows 4 recent visitors. If my client add a new visitor in the backend... This new visitor will show up a older one is disappearing...

But now my client wants to show one visitor (kermit the kicker) always on the left.

So i want to put that visitor hard coded in...
First i tried to put into the home.tpl...
But then it shows up out of the div around the view, and that f*** up my design. I used the classes from the view to style...

So now I want to put the HTML-code into the view self (within the divs from the view), put i don't find the solution...

Anybody? I tried some options "HEADER" in the view, but there is no space showing up where i can put the HTML-Code in...

Thanks for reading and support :-)

Kristof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the header add the type **Global: Unfiltered text** and enter your HTML there.

A more Drupalish way would be

1. Mark "Kermit the Frog" as *Sticky at top of lists* in it's *Publishing options* on it's node edit form.
2. Alter the *Sort criteria* your View to have two criteria: *Content: Sticky (DESC)* followed by *Content: Post date (DESC)*.

Comment: Thanks QueenVictoria! But solutions work... 
I used the drupalish way ;-) First i did not find the option 'sticky at the top' because i look for that option in the view options... but after i realised i had to opt-in that option on the content itself :-)

Comment: Thanks Stan glad it helped. I've updated the answer to make it clearer.